# Failed to start Load Kernel Modules IT8688E

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel-modules, hardware, sensors

[image]

Since the motherboard's IT8688E chip is not supported I forced the 8628 one as in [this Github `lm-sensors` issue](https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/154) and it detected all sensors correctly.

This is what I did to make it work:

- Added `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in /etc/default/grub.
- Created the `/etc/modules-load.d/it87.conf` file with a `it87` line
- Created the `/etc/modprobe.d/it87.conf` file with a `options it87 force_id=0x8628` line
- `# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`

But then plasma was freezing when logging out and I undid everything. Now I get this at boot:

```
out 07 07:09:44 d3.localdomain kernel: it87: Found IT8628E chip at 0xa40, revision 1
out 07 07:09:44 d3.localdomain kernel: it87: Beeping is supported
out 07 07:09:44 d3.localdomain kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000A45-0x0000000000000A46 conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000A45-0x0000000000000A46 (\GSA1.SIO1) (20200528/utaddress-204)
out 07 07:09:44 d3.localdomain kernel: ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
out 07 07:09:44 d3.localdomain kernel: fuse: init (API version 7.31)
out 07 07:09:44 d3.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
out 07 07:09:44 d3.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
out 07 07:09:44 d3.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
out 07 07:09:44 d3.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1602065384.576:2): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='unit=systemd-modules-load comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
```

How to get rid off it?

```
$ uname -a
Linux d3.localdomain 5.8.13-200.fc32.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 1 21:49:42 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I don't see any boot delay delay, it's the same timestamp right after the module gets loaded.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov What about that range warning?

Comment: It's pretty much harmless - but it also means the said driver cannot work due to a bug in the kernel: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204807 You could chime in as well.

Answer (score 1):

IT8688 may be similar to some other ITE chip, but 8628 isn't it. You want a driver specifically supporting that: **https://github.com/frankcrawford/it87**

As for the IO range warning, if it's not already solved by the above I feel like the new-ish gigabyte WMI driver should have helped.